# Draggable not working in jQuery for current selected Div

Tags: jquery, events, draggable, drag

A simple thing but not working i don't know what is the problem.

```
jQuery(topbar).mousedown(function(event){       
       var sel_to=jQuery(event.target).parent().attr("id");
       jQuery("#sel_to").draggable();
});
```

Comment: You are targeting an element with the id "sel_to", dont you want

Comment: parent div of topbar div is newWindow, I want to drag the parent div when topbar.mousedown.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want something closer to:

```
JQuery("#" + sel_to).draggable();
```

Comment: guys thank you.. problem solved. i didnt load the plugins :S and Marc, ur solution helped me.